# Show Unity Line Renderer as 3d cable or wire

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, materials, line-renderer

I am dynamically making a line renderer which is pull by the character to show that a character is pulling a wire. The line renderer working fine but unfortunately its display is not according to my expectation. Like it showing as 2D.

Is there any way available to make it more realistic wire/cable? Maybe any shader will help ?

Comment: need some more information, please.  A screenshot would go a long way here

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is activate the generateLightingData option. Then depending of what you want to make use a custom material with a shader to render what you want. For example you could use a standart shader with a 3d cable normal map/albedo/metalic texture to get a pretty good looking cable. In the case of wanting a chain it will be harder since you will need an alpha transparency mask to hide (transparent) the parts between each chain. I highly recomend you to use a shader program (like Amplify Shader Editor) or use the new shader graph in unity 2018+ if you never used shaders before.